Spring WebFlux Security ServerHttpSecurity
I'm working with Spring WebFlux Security and trying to bypass the token validation filter for specific endpoints, like /auth/api/v1/cred/login/. Despite using the permitAll() method for that endpoint, the request still reaches the token validation filter, and I'm not able to skip it for this particular path.
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        log.info("Request enters into API Gateway");
        http.csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec -> authorizeExchangeSpec
                .pathMatchers("/auth/api/v1/cred/**").permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(tokenValidation, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .addFilterAfter(addXTrustedSourceHeaderFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .httpBasic(HttpBasicSpec::disable)
                .formLogin(FormLoginSpec::disable);
        return http.build();
    }

Even though I'm explicitly calling permitAll() for /api/v1/cred/login/, the request still enters the token validation filter. I’ve verified the endpoint is correct and logged it, but it doesn't seem to bypass the filter as expected.
What am I missing? Why is the request still reaching the token validation filter despite using permitAll()?

Whats the reason for the homemade security?

@Toerktumlare, In my API Gateway configuration, all downstream services are accessible only through the API Gateway. Token validation occurs at the API Gateway level, and a custom header is added after successful validation. Each downstream service then verifies this custom header.
However, I have some open endpoints such as /login and /register. Despite configuring permitAll() for these endpoints, my custom token validation filter is still being executed for all requests.

Well you have basically opted out of best practices and spring security with your home made security solution so dont expect spring security to work anymore. Good luck

permitAll only used in http.authorizeExchange(...) generated AuthorizationWebFilter. When you custom own filters need to handle path alone as below:
public class TokenValidation implements WebFilter {
    
    private final ServerWebExchangeMatcher matcher;

    public TokenValidation() {
        this.matcher = ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/auth/api/v1/cred/**");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return this.matcher.matches(exchange).filter(ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult::isMatch)
                .switchIfEmpty(chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.empty()))
                .flatMap(s -> {
                    //Token Validation Logic
                    return Mono.just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("","", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"))).then();
                });
    }

}


As per my understanding you are trying to say like if whenever we use any custom filter and add into security chain, all the request will reach that custom filter even-though its permitAll(). There we need to write custom logic inside custom filter to handle permitAll request?

You are correct

Thanks @DingHao
